# How to get the transfer function out of a Bode Curve on a datasheet?

Tags: signal, control-system, signal-processing, texas-instruments, bode-plot

I am trying to find the transfer function of AMC1350 out of its datasheet. I dont have any information about which degree of a lowpass filter or what kind it has. DC gain is 2/5.  Cutoff frequency is 300kHz, at 300 Khz it has a phase shift of -180deg. I thought it would be  a PT4 system.
With a transfer function that looks like: H(s) = 1/( (s/w) +1 )^4. where w = 2*pi*f_c.

So I wrote a quick script to check if I was right. Here is the script.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control
import math

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# requires coefficients of the numerator and denominator polynomials
# the coefficients are given starting with the highest power of s

f_c = 300*(10**3)
print(f_c)
p = 2*(math.pi)*f_c
Q = 1

A_DC = (2*(math.pi)*f_c)**4

A = 4*p
B=6*(p**2)
C=4*(p**3)
D= p**4


G = 1*control.tf([0,A_DC],[1,A,B,C,D])
print(G)

mag,phase,omega = control.bode(G,Hz=True,dB=True,deg=True)

# Find the index of the cutoff frequency where magnitude is -3 dB
cutoff_idx = np.argmin(np.abs(mag + 3))

# Get the corresponding cutoff frequency
cutoff_frequency = omega[cutoff_idx]
print(f"Cutoff Frequency: {cutoff_frequency} Hz")
```

At this point I realised that at 300kHz the Amplitude would be -12dB. And the bode curve could not be that of a PT4 System. I am wondering if it is even feasible to translate this Bode Plot into a transfer function. If possible I would like to find it, to be able to simulate the rest of the circuits behaviour using python. Any help would be appriciated.
[image]

Comment: The phase plot indicates that the system also has a small delay

Comment: The asymptote seems to be -18dB/octave or a 3rd order filter; this explains the rapidly rising (well, falling as plotted) phase shift above cutoff. What poles (and zeros if applicable) it has can be found by curve fitting to whatever degree of accuracy is desired (with the results becoming unreasonable as noise begins to dominate / overfitting occurs). In general, this uses Pade approximants; I'm afraid I don't have any sample code however.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/product/AMC1350#design-tools-simulation has links to _AMC1350 PSpice Model_ and _AMC1350 TINA-TI Reference Design_ Simulation Models. Do they have more information than in the datasheet?

Answer (score 2):

> *How to get the transfer function out of a Bode Curve on a datasheet?*

- The transfer function (TF) is the ultimate statement of the response of a linear circuit
- The bode plot is an information-degraded version of the TF: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/).

- The bode plot is degraded from the TF because it only contains information on the \$j\omega\$ plane

Therefore, it's theoretically impossible to construct a TF from a bode plot. This is because the bode plot contains a subset of the information within the TF. Of course we can use intuition and a little guesswork along the way but, we can never be truly sure.

> *I am wondering if it is even feasible to translate this Bode Plot into
> a transfer function.*

Theoretically no but, with a little guesswork and some assumptions then maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Emre:
I am afraid that the best way to determine the transfer function from the datasheet is through a process of trial and error. Since there is very little data to start with, it is hard to get very accurate.  You can assume that all the poles in the circuit are real, and then assume all the poles in the circuit are at the same frequency, and it sounds like that is what you are doing at the moment. When I tried to do that, I get a guess that there may be 8 poles, (all at about 800KHz). This may be as close as you need. Note that there is a graph of the step response of the device in the data sheet, indicating some overshoot in the response, and a rise time of 1.177usec.  Since there is overshoot, you can be assured that there are actually some complex poles in the device, so "all real poles" is not a good assumption.  The simple 8 pole model has a rise time of 1.57usec.
I don't know how much time you want to devote to this, but you could write a computer program that does more sophisticated curve fitting to the frequency response, or to the step response, depending on which domain you are interested in simulating in Python. Probably lots of trouble for not much gain.